# Rails4 method: :patch at index page using jquery/ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Would like to ask, how to make something like, lets says i have table Post and have column status (which is could be publish or unpublish).. so at the posts#index, i've button to mark as publish or unpublish.

```
<%= link_to 'Publish', post, method: :patch, remote: true %>
<%= link_to 'Unpublish', post, method: :patch, remote: true %>
```

So what I want is to update the status field through ajax using method patch.. Can someone give me an idea how to it?

Comment: try `<%= link_to 'Publish', action: patch, method: post, remote: true %> `

Comment: @RajarshiDas so how to know that will update the status column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than one way to do this. Here's a simple and straight forward way.
In the view:

```
<%= link_to 'Publish', publish_post_path, method: :patch, remote: true %>
<%= link_to 'Unpublish', unpublish_post_path, method: :patch, remote: true %>
```

And add them to your config/routes.rb. This will provide the `publish_post_path` used in the view and direct them to the `publish` action in `posts_controller`

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    patch :publish
    patch :unpublish
  end
end
```

and finally, add the 2 actions to your controller:

```
  def publish
    ...
  end

  def unpublish
    ...
  end
```